# Img load while refreshing

Tags: css, html

Last 2 days I'm working with the https://www.memo-ict.nl/ site, but my problem is that the logo in my menubar is showing up in the refresh. I just would like to have the img showing up when the refresh is done!

Can you guys help me? Because I'm stick with that problem for just a day.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are resizing your logo in your css, giving that flash of unstyled content on load/reload.  It's original size is 150x150px. You have at least two options:

1. Change it for a smaller version (75x75px), avoiding the jarring resize.
2. Alter the css to make it display:none (like your other logos) and make it fade in with javascript.

Give these a try.